# Level 15, State 1, Line 136 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    c.customer_Id, SUM(total_amt), DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) as DOB
FROM 
    Transactions T
INNER JOIN 
    Customer C ON T.cust_id = C.customer_Id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_Id, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE())
HAVING
    (DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 35)
    AND (SELECT tran_date
         FROM Transactions
         HAVING tran_date BETWEEN DATEADD (DAY , -30, MAX(tran_date)) AND MAX(tran_date))
```

I am getting this error while executing the above code:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 136
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results help.  A non-working query does not necessary convey this information.

Comment: `SELECT tran_date ...` subquery returns some dataset, not boolean. Maybe `EXISTS` operator is lost? But it is non-correlated, "always true" in general, and it uses explicit GROUP BY.\

Answer (score 0):

If you want a summary each customer's most recent 30 days of transaction where the customers are between 25 and 35 years old, then you basically want to filter *before* aggregation:

```
SELECT c.customer_Id, SUM(total_amt), DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) as DOB
FROM Customer C JOIN
     (SELECT T.*,
             MAX(tran_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) as max_tran_date
      FROM Transactions T
     ) T
     ON T.cust_id = C.customer_Id
WHERE DOB >= DATEADD(YEAR, -35, GETDATE()) AND
      DOB < DATEADD(YEAR, -24, GETDATE()) AND
      t.tran_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, max_tran_date)
GROUP BY c.customer_Id, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE());
```

Comment: I am actually trying to find "For all customers aged between 25 to 35 years find what is the net total revenue generated by these consumers in last 30 days of transactions from max transaction date available in the data?"

Comment: @Priyanshu . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: @Priyanshu Could you leave a sample of your data ? It could be the input-data, which is causing the problem, and that's hard to identify without any datasample.

Comment: @Atmira please sind the sample data

Comment: @GordonLinoff please sind the sample data